# PHP face detection: cloudinary API face count

Tags: php, api, face-detection, cloudinary

I'm using the cloudinary face detection API this way:

```
require 'cloudinary/Cloudinary.php';
require 'cloudinary/Uploader.php';
require 'cloudinary/Api.php';

\Cloudinary::config(array(
    "cloud_name" => "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "api_key" => "9999999999999",
    "api_secret" => "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
));

$img = 'guy.jpg';
$imgid = time() . 'guy';

\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($img, array("public_id" => $imgid));

$url = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/xxxxxx/image/upload/c_fill,g_face,h_500,w_375/' . $imgid . '.jpg';
file_put_contents('cropped' . $img, file_get_contents($url));
```

But what I also need is:

```
\Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($img, array("public_id" => $imgid));

// what I need >>>
if('face_count != 1')
{
    exit;
}
// <<< what I need

$url = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/xxxxxx/image/upload/c_fill,g_face,h_500,w_375/' . $imgid . '.jpg';
file_put_contents('cropped' . $img, file_get_contents($url));
```

I don't understand how to use the face_count from the doc here: http://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_transformations#specifying_conditions

Comment: It depends on what you would like to achieve in the case of (face-count != 1). Generally such URL will look like: https:// res.cloudinary.com/xxxxxx/image/upload/if_fc_eq_1/c_fill,g_face,h_500,w_375/if_else/some-fallback-transformation/if_end/sample.jpg

Anyhow, an image must be delivered, otherwise it will cause an error (broken image).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer Nadav, I solved it this way:

```
$url = 'http://res.cloudinary.com/xxxxxxx/image/upload/if_fc_eq_1,c_fill,g_face,h_500,w_375/' . $bildnamecloud . '.jpg';
file_put_contents('cropped' . $bildname, file_get_contents($url));

\Cloudinary\Uploader::destroy($bildnamecloud);


list($width, $height) = getimagesize('cropped' . $bildname);

if($width == 375 AND $height == 500)
{

}
else
{

}
```